# Scanf before gets causes gets to be skipped due to new-line character

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand how `gets` works if it's used after `scanf`.

```
int main()
{
    char c,d;
    char word[20];
    int n;

    printf("give a number:\n");
    scanf("%d ",&n);                           //     (input 1)

    // c=getchar();                                   (Solution 1)
    // while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ;  (Solution 2)
    // fflush(stdin);                                 (Solution 3)
    // gets(word);                                    (Solution 4)

    printf("Give a word:\n");
    gets(word);                                  //   (input 2)

    printf("word = %s ",word);                   //   (Output)
}
```

I know this question is asked a lot here, and that I shouldn't use `gets` at all (instead I should use `fgets`). However, I have to use it since it's the only thing we were taught in class. I've read plenty of posts about it. I've found multiple solutions to evade that problem. but I still don't understand some of these solutions.

If I start my program without any of the solutions, `gets` will read the new-line character `\n` and won't let me give any input.

I found that this can be bypassed if I use:

- (Solution 1) however let's say the user in (input 1) typed:

  ```
  1   aaaaaaaaaaa \n
  ```

  (Output) will be "   aaaaaaaaaaa "
- (Solution 2) will fix this problem and will let me give (input 2).
- (Solution 3) works too; however, it's frowned upon as it doesn't have a good portability.
- (Solution 4) is the same as (solution 2) I suppose. Please tell me if I'm wrong.
- Another solution I found is to always use `gets` whenever I want to give input; and then format it with `sscanf(...)`. Tried it! It fixed all my problems. This is what I started using.

I don't really understand Solution 2. I can see that it removes all characters besides `\n` and then removes the first `\n` it meets and stops the loop.
But what if the user gave this as his input

```
\n \n \n               1    abc \n
```

Why are the first 3 '\n' ignored? I don't understand the buffer notion that well.

Please let me know if I got something wrong in those solutions!

EDIT: 
I already know about `scanf(" %c",...);` but my problem is with `gets` and not `scanf`.

Comment: @jonathan leffler I know about using space before %c in scanf, this is not the same question. As this has to do with gets() and not scanf

Comment: You should worry about a class that teaches you to use `gets()` — it is teaching you bad practices from the start, which isn't going to help you in industry.  Tell (well, maybe don't) your teacher that C11 abandoned `gets()` — announced in 2007, implemented in 2011 — because it is [Impossible to use `gets()` safely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/). So, it has been at least 5 years, arguably 10, since the standards body dropped a hint.  But the first (Morris) Internet Worm back in 1988 used `gets()` as one of its way around!

Comment: I know I shouldn't use gets at all due to its buffer problems and how it can use memory it shoudln't use. But, sadly I have to use it for this class. I'm trying to understand how it works and how can I play around its multiple problems.

Comment: You've got a `scanf()` and it leaves the newline in the buffer.  There's also a trailing blank in the format string; you can have another relevant duplicate [What is the effect of a trailing blank in a `scanf()` format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/) if you like.  The problems are very much the same — mixing line-based input with `scanf()`-based input is hard to get right and most people don't.  If you want line-based input, use `fgets()` et al to read and then `sscanf()` to parse.

Comment: so far i've been using solely this for anything other than strings


gets(line); sscanf(line,"%f",&something);

and gets($string_name) for strings  Is this correct?

Comment: Your first three newlines are ignored because `scanf()` skips them as white space before the first number.  The `scanf()` function doesn't care about newlines except to the extent they're 'white space' that gets skipped by every format specifier except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.  All the other formats skip leading white space.  So, `scanf("%d ", &n)` first skips leading white space, then reads a number, and then waits to find a non-white-space character (which it ignores and puts back for the next input operation, but it has to read up to that character before it completes).

Comment: Solution 2 assumes that any characters after the number but before the newline are not relevant — there's no chance that the user typed 1M meaning `1000000` (or `1048576`), for example.  It skips over any non-digits after the number, up to and including the newline (or EOF).  If that's what you want (it often is), it's good; if it's not what you want, it's bad.  But the controlling factor is what you want your program to do with the extra input.

Comment: Using `fgets()` with `sscanf()` when appropriate is usually the best way to go. It has major benefits when it comes to trying alternative formats and error reporting.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir you're awesome! That was really helpful. I hope I can give back to the community someday too